# Minimal working example of Cask project with ert-test?

Tags: cask

I want to use [Cask](https://github.com/cask/cask) for development, but have trouble getting it set up.

Could anyone please show a minimal example with one package file, one function and one ert-test and which commands you need to 1) run the tests and 2) install the package?

Just something simple like an add function, and a test for 2+2.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at a small package?

Comment: Haven't found one. All the examples linked to in the old wiki are rather large so if something breaks, you do not know why.

Comment: There are plenty of potential packages on MELPA.  Take a look at [seq.el](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el) for instance.

Comment: @lunaryorn why don't you add that comment as an answer? It helped me, and I would vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

Per [lunaryorn](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/227/lunaryorn)'s comment, Have a look at [seq.el](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el). It's a good example of a small Cask project.